# Limit access of list items based on user

Tags: list, permissions, item-level-permissions

So, I have a list of projects, with a bunch of bidders bidding on and winning those projects. My sharepoint site is a communication portal with a list that contains project information, statuses and etc.

The site is initially set up to share information internally and the access to this particular list is blocked. However, I am wanting bidders to have the ability to access this list in the future to update the list with the latest information (status, timeline updates, project documentation, etc) if they have won the project. However, I do not want the bidders to be able to view in any way the other projects they have not won, for very obvious reasons.

I understand this can be easily done with a filter, but I am uncertain how I can restrict access of other contents for a project they have not won. Any suggestions on how I can implement this other than changing unique permissions of all the projects on the list?

I have reviewed some other solutions, but it does not seem to provide a viable solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing all this on one list? The way I've handled it in the past is to create  site per project. That gives each project a place to store requirements docs, as well as a separate issues list and task list. Since permissions are simple to set up on a site basis, this makes it easy to share out the site with the appropriate users.

But if you're just targeting a single list, you can certain set up permissions on an item basis. Do not go the route of filters, as filters are not security. A knowledgeable user could simple access the entire list and bypass any filters. If setting up permissions for each item is too time consuming, you could also create a workflow (with the 2010 workflow engine) that changes the permissions based on some condition, though that might be tricky with external users.

Comment: Creating multiple sites is possible, but aggregating information from multiple sites into one single display is quite difficult - which is the goal of the original list in the first place. I can technically do the translation work myself, but I am trying to cut out the double handling by my vendors and no-value-added work to my day to day. Thanks for the suggestion though, Do you have a some guidelines on changing permissions with workflow? Thanks!!

Comment: Aggregating data from multiple sites can be done with search web parts. (That's what they're designed for). But there's lots of walkthroughs for changing permissions via workflow, like this one: http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to have access to their own items.  You can set the permissions from the list setting.
[image]

If this doesn't meet your requirement, I would suggest move the items to another list through a workflow. Setting permissions on the individual items (through workflow) might be okay, if you have any few hundred items but not great if you have thousands of items.

Comment: This will work except that the admin will be the person creating all the initial entries (pre-award). It appears that if the created by field is not something that is changable by the UI, so this will probably not be ideal unless there is a workaround to allow the admin to set the created by field.

Comment: I don't think you mentioned this requirement in the original question.  Yes, created by cannot be updated.  Above answers also doesn't allow you to change created by field.